# Trouble copying bitmapped images to pasteboard in cocoa osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bitmap

I'm writing an image processing app that that calculates bitmapped images. It displays them in multiple windows and I want to be able to copy images to the pasteboard. Each window has it's own controller (sub class of NSWindowController) and imageView (subclass of NSImageView).

My code will successfully copy the image from the most recently displayed window, but gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1) when I copy from a previously displayed window.

The code in the window controller for setting up the bitmapped image is this:

```
-(void) placeImage:(NSRect) theRect{
    windowRect = theRect;
    [[self window] setTitle:windowName];

    NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                                initWithBitmapDataPlanes: iBitmap.getpixdatap()
                                pixelsWide: iBitmap.getwidth() pixelsHigh: iBitmap.getheight()
                                bitsPerSample: 8 samplesPerPixel: 4 hasAlpha: YES isPlanar:NO
                                colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                bytesPerRow: 4*iBitmap.getwidth()
                                bitsPerPixel: 32];

    NSImage* im = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(iBitmap.getwidth(), iBitmap.getheight())];
    [im addRepresentation:bitmap];

    //NSImage* im = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:@"./Contents/Resources/curve.jpg"];

    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowRect.size.width,windowRect.size.height-TITLEBAR_HEIGHT);
    [imageView setFrame:rect];
    [imageView setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
    [imageView setImage:im];
    [imageView display];

}
```

For the copy operation:

```
- (IBAction)copy:sender {
    NSImage *image = [imageView image];
    if (image != nil) {
        NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteboard clearContents];
        NSArray *copiedObjects = @[image];
        [pasteboard writeObjects:copiedObjects];
    }
}
```

If I replace the bitmapped image with an image from a jpeg file (commented out line in placeImage above), then the copy is successful for any window. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The stack frames look like this:

0 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem

1 vImageCopyBuffer

2 Copy_Convert

3 AnyToAnyBiock

4 vImageConvert_AnyToAny

5 ConvertBytesWithRange

6 _CGimagePiuginWriteTIFF

7 CGimageOestinationFinalize

8 +[NSBitmaplmageRep(NSBitmaplmageFileTypeExtensions) representationOflmageRepslnArray:usingType:properties:]

9 -[NStmage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:factot:]

10 -[NSimage pasteboardPropertylistForType:]

11 -[NSPasteboard writeObjects:]

12 -[DataWindowController copy:]

13 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]

14 -[NSMenultem _corePerformAction]

15 -[NSCarbonMenulmpl performActionWithHighlightingForltemAtlndex:]

16 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:]

17 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:]

18 -[NSApplication sendEvent:]

19 -[NSApplication run]

20 NSApplicationMain

21 main

22 start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is evidently a memory management issue. Helpful information was here:
[question 16094748](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094748/cocoa-memory-management-when-using-initwithbitmapdataplanes-to-create-nsimage?rq=1)

Initializing the bitmap data plane with nil and then copying the data over explicitly seems to solve the problem.

```
-(void) placeImage:(NSRect) theRect{
    windowRect = theRect;
    [[self window] setTitle:windowName];

    NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                                initWithBitmapDataPlanes: nil
                                pixelsWide: iBitmap.getwidth() pixelsHigh: iBitmap.getheight()
                                bitsPerSample: 8 samplesPerPixel: 4 hasAlpha: YES isPlanar:NO
                                colorSpaceName:NSCustomColorSpace
                                bytesPerRow: 4*iBitmap.getwidth()  
                                bitsPerPixel: 32];

    memcpy([bitmap  bitmapData], iBitmap.getpixdata(), iBitmap.getheight()*iBitmap.getwidth()*4);

    NSImage* im = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(iBitmap.getwidth(), iBitmap.getheight())];
    [im addRepresentation:bitmap];

    //NSImage* im = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:@"./Contents/Resources/curve.jpg"];

    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowRect.size.width,windowRect.size.height-TITLEBAR_HEIGHT);
    [imageView setFrame:rect];
    [imageView setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
    [imageView setImage:im];
    [imageView display];

}
```